# How to solve " `+': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)" Error in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Working my way through the Odin Project and stuck on a Ruby exercise, where you take in a number input and spit out the plane english version of the number.  Getting the error referring to the bolded section below (line 32)

```
def englishNumber number
  if number < 0  # No negative numbers.
    return 'Please enter a number that isn\'t negative.'
  end
  if number == 0
    return 'zero'
  end

  numString = ''  # This is the string we will return.

  onesPlace = ['one',     'two',       'three',    'four',     'five',
               'six',     'seven',     'eight',    'nine']
  tensPlace = ['ten',     'twenty',    'thirty',   'forty',    'fifty',
               'sixty',   'seventy',   'eighty',   'ninety']
  teenagers = ['eleven',  'twelve',    'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen',
               'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']


  left  = number
  write = left/10000          
  left  = left - write*10000

  if write > 0

    if ((write == 1) and (left > 0))
      **numString = numString + teenagers[left-1] + ' thousand'**

      left = 0
    else
      numString = numString + tensPlace[write-1] + ' thousand'


    if left > 0
      numString = numString + '-'
    end
  end

  write = left/1000          
  left  = left - write*1000

  if write > 0


      if left > 0
        numString = numString + ' '
      end
    end

  write = left/100          
  left  = left - write*100  

  if write > 0


    if left > 0
      numString = numString + ' '
    end
  end

  write = left/10          
  left  = left - write*10  

  if write > 0
    if ((write == 1) and (left > 0))

      left = 0
    else
      numString = numString + tensPlace[write-1]
      # The "-1" is because tensPlace[3] is 'forty', not 'thirty'.
    end

    if left > 0
      numString = numString + '-'
    end
  end

  write = left  
  left  = 0     

  if write > 0
    numString = numString + onesPlace[write-1]
    # The "-1" is because onesPlace[3] is 'four', not 'three'.
  end

  # Now we just return "numString"...
  numString
end

puts englishNumber 10100
```

Comment: In the first condition `if write > 0` you have `if-else` but no `end`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the statement `teenagers[left-1]`. For the input 10100,

`left` = 100 and `teenagers[100-1]` = `teenagers[99]` = `nil`.

You can't concatenate a string with a `nil` object. You could solve this in a number of ways.

One way is to replace your condition with

```
if ((write == 1) and (left > 0) and teenagers[left-1])
```

The last expression will be true if the value is not `nil`

If you run the program, you should be able to see `ten thousand-` for the input `10100`. Now, work on your algorithm to make it return the number of `hundreds` in the input.

You're also missing an `end` after the `if .. else` block inside `if write > 0`

Hope this helps!